# HTTP POST Content-Type

Tags: vb.net, iis, http-headers, http-post, content-type

I have this HTTP POST service:

```
POST /test/test.asmx/getValues HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

xmlstr=string
```

I want have this service:

```
POST /test/test.asmx/getValues HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: length

xmlstr=string
```

How can i change Server's **Content-Type** value to **application/xml**?
I'm using IIS and VB .NET.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` request header describes the format of the data in the body of the request.

`xmlstr=string` is encoded using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

If you said `Content-Type: application/xml` then I'd expect the body for me formatted as XML  (e.g. `<xmlstr>string</xmlstr>`).

The Content-Type you send to the server has no standardised influence over what type of data the server responds with.

[The `Accept` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) can request specific content types:

```
POST /test/test.asmx/getValues HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length

xmlstr=string
```

… but the server side code has to pay attention to it and respect it.

Servers might also allow specific formats to be requested with non-standard request headers, data stored in the query string of the URL, or data in the body.

It will always depend on what the server side code supports.